# How to create Stored Procedure using SQL 2012?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a table "employers"

```
Employerid int
InsuranceNumber varchar(10)
Ministry nvarchar(100)
Adress nvarchar(250)
PostalCode varchar(50)
Phone varchar(14)
Mobile varchar(14)
Email nvarchar(60)
UserName nvarchar(50)
Password nvarchar(50)
ContactPerson nvarchar(250)
EntryDate datetime
LastUpdateDate datetime
IsDeleted bit
Active bit
```

and i have created how to insert data using insert stored proc

```
Create procedure dbo.Employers_Insert
@InsuranceNumber nvarchar(10),
@Ministry nvarchar(100),
@Adress nvarchar(250),
@PostalCode varchar(50),
@Phone varchar(14),
@Mobile varchar(14),
@Email nvarchar(60),
@UserName nvarchar(50),
@Password nvarchar(50),
@ContactPerson nvarchar(250),
@EntryDate datetime,
@LastUpdateDate datetime,
@IsDeleted bit,
@Active bit
-->AS
-->BEGAIN
Insert Employers (InsuranceNumber, Ministry, Adress , PostalCode ,
Phone, Mobile , Email, UserName , [Password] , ContactPerson, EntryDate,
LastUpdateDate, IsDeleted, Active)
values (@InsuranceNumber, @Ministry, @Adress , @PostalCode ,
@Phone, @Mobile , @Email, @UserName , @[Password] , @ContactPerson, EntryDate,
@LastUpdateDate, @IsDeleted, @Active)
End
```

i still need to create Search , GetByID , GetByPage , GetList .. Stored Procedures please.. :)
any help ?

Comment: Have a look at an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate and be done with generating procs to do CRUD operations.

Comment: Yeah stop wasting your time and your employers money doing fully redunndant work - stuff like that is a "get me fired" invitation.

Comment: @TomTom except when your employer or customer insist on things getting done like this.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar No, even then. Stuff like that can be totally automated. Write a T4 template and get those SP's automatically generated.

Comment: @user22387 Well, it is everyones business the moment you read it and - is it not amazing that in the IT world it is ok to call oneself incompetent when get5ting paid? I never saw a lawyer or doctor say "hey, i am incompetent, it is ok for me to make mistakes because I am still learning, now take that pills". Get some respect for your profession, please.

Comment: Ok thank you for your advice MR Professional :)

Comment: @TomTom I totally disagree with you. Generating SPs per hand is *not*  a sign of incompetence and there are cases when this even is a good thing. Maybe in your world the use of an ORM or other tools to automatically create SPs is a must - there are, however, other places outside your world when people like and need to know what's going on on the database side. And this is when we manually create SPs.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Oh, I totally agree. I write stored procedures by hand regularly. Just not for stuff that a stript can do. How much intelligence do you think does it take to do a "insert data into table"? You have ZERO flexibility in there. Same with "get table by ID". I have tons of SP's here that do complex transformation and analysis - but all of them have logic in there that is specific and optimized. None of the examples given here require any intelligence more than following a strict script how to handle the particular data. I personalyl think programmers should be smarter than that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear.
The correct procedure code to insert a record:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Employers_Insert
(
    @InsuranceNumber nvarchar(10),
    @Ministry nvarchar(100),
    @Adress nvarchar(250),
    @PostalCode varchar(50),
    @Phone varchar(14),
    @Mobile varchar(14),
    @Email nvarchar(60),
    @UserName nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(50),
    @ContactPerson nvarchar(250),
    @EntryDate datetime,
    @LastUpdateDate datetime,
    @IsDeleted bit,
    @Active bit
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.Employers 
    (
            InsuranceNumber, Ministry, Adress, PostalCode,
            Phone, Mobile, Email, UserName, [Password], ContactPerson, EntryDate,
            LastUpdateDate, IsDeleted, ACTIVE
    )
    VALUES 
    (
            @InsuranceNumber, @Ministry, @Adress, @PostalCode,
            @Phone, @Mobile, @Email, @UserName, @Password, @ContactPerson, @EntryDate,
            @LastUpdateDate, @IsDeleted, @Active
    )

END
```

Also you need specify column EmployerId with IDENTITY specification if EmployerId is autoincrement or you need pass EmployerId as parameter of stored procedure.

You have problem with dbo.Employers_Insert or your need code for Search, GetByID, GetByPage, GetList ?

Comment: i also need also need code for Search, GetByID, GetByPage, GetList ?

Comment: i also need Search, GetByID, GetByPage, GetList..what does meaning friend

Comment: To write "Searh" procedure you must specify which parameters need for employees search. For GetByPage, GetList you must describe more detailed business logic.
GetEmployerById procedure may look like:

Comment: i mean by GetPage S-P is how to send the page index then it back for me with a page of Employers .. 10 employers for example!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your business requirements you can write a Search procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_EmployersSearch
    @Employerid int,-- Add here all the search parameters you'll send from application
    @InsuranceNumber nvarchar(10),
    @Ministry nvarchar(100),
    @Adress nvarchar(250),
    @PostalCode varchar(50),
    @Phone varchar(14),
    @Mobile varchar(14),
    @Email nvarchar(60),
    @UserName nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(50),
    @ContactPerson nvarchar(250),
    @EntryDate datetime,
    @LastUpdateDate datetime,
    @IsDeleted bit,
    @Active bit
AS
SELECT InsuranceNumber,-- Add here all the columns you want to  send back to application
       Ministry,
       Adress ,
       PostalCode ,
       Phone,
       Mobile ,
       Email,
       UserName ,
       [Password] ,
       ContactPerson,
       EntryDate,
       LastUpdateDate,
       IsDeleted,
       Active
FROM employers
WHERE     (@Employerid IS NULL OR Employerid = @Employerid)
      AND (@InsuranceNumber IS NULL OR InsuranceNumber LIKE '%' + @InsuranceNumber + '%')
      AND (@Ministry IS NULL OR Ministry LIKE '%' + @Ministry + '%')
      AND (@Adress IS NULL OR Adress LIKE '%' + @Adress + '%')
      AND (@PostalCode IS NULL OR PostalCode = @PostalCode)
      --You can add search conditions here based on your business requirements
```

Comment: Also you can create procedures for GetByID , GetByPage , GetList on same lines just change the input parameter list, searched columns and selected columns based on your business requirements.

Comment: actually i've created the search Stored proc and the GetById Stored Procedure..but i dunno how to create the get by page one.. how to send the Page index? , and the get list one!